# accesing post variables in array

Tags: php

how can I keep post variables through all the functions in php class?
I'm accessing post variables in a array in function. But when I try to access those in another function it retrvies only the last element in array.

```
foreach ( $questionAry as $questionID )
{
        $questionName = $this->htmlID_questionID . $questionID;

        $question_answer = $_POST[$questionName];                   

        $_SESSION['qusID'] = $questionID;
        $_SESSION['qusanswer'] = $question_answer;
}
```

I want to access $questionID and $question_answer in another function. I tried to do it through session, but I can only access last value.

Comment: You`re doing well.  Define each $_POST[] element as a variable and use it over,  if need to parse between pages, hold it in a **session**.  Call each session afterwards when needed.

Comment: my problem is I can acess only the last element of array.how can I get all the values in there?

Comment: Ok,  $questionID=$_POST[$questionID];  $question_answer = $_POST[$questionName];.  Here you have two arrays composed by the many elements inside each $_POST[$questionName] and each $_POST[$questionID].  Now to use them  you have to loop through the array, with foreach( $questionID as $q_id=>$val_qid),  this way you can grab each element,  insert into the tables,  or do whatever need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong...these guys are getting overwritten on every iteration

```
    $_SESSION['qusID'] = $questionID;
    $_SESSION['qusanswer'] = $question_answer;
```

You need to use an indexed loop, something like so...

```
foreach ( $questionAry as $key => $questionID )
{
        $questionName = $this->htmlID_questionID . $questionID;

        $question_answer = $_POST[$questionName];                   

        $_SESSION['qusID'][$key] = $questionID;
        $_SESSION['qusanswer'][$key] = $question_answer;
}
```

**EDIT: based on conversation below, try something like so.**

```
function getvalues() { 
    $questions = array();
    $jsonEncoded = ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) ? stripslashes($_POST[$this->htmlID_questionIDAry]) : $_POST[$this->htmlID_questionIDAry]; 
    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonEncoded); 

    $questionAry = explode(",",$jsonDecoded->list); 
    $instr = ""; 

    foreach ( $questionAry as $key => $questionID ) { 
        $questions[$key]['name'] = $this->htmlID_questionID . $questionID; 
        $questions[$key]['answer'] = $_POST[$questionName]; 
    } 

    return $questions;
}


$parsedQuestions = getvalues();

name_of_other_function($parsedQuestions);

function name_of_other_function($parsedQuestions){
    print_r($parsedQuestions);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.without using session how can I keep those post variable available for another function?

Comment: In the same page? It might help if you posted the full function, or a gist with the file. 

You shouldn't need to use a session unless you need the variables to persist across page loads.

Comment: the same page in a different function.

Comment: function getvalues()
 {
  $jsonEncoded = ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) ? stripslashes($_POST[$this->htmlID_questionIDAry]) : $_POST[$this->htmlID_questionIDAry];  
  $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonEncoded);
  $questionAry = explode(",",$jsonDecoded->list);
  $instr = "";
  foreach ( $questionAry as $key => $questionID  )
  {
   $questionName = $this->htmlID_questionID . $questionID;
                    $question_answer = $_POST[$questionName];
          
 } 
} want to acess quesionID and question_answer out side of this function.

Comment: I can access values in different function. funfunction accessvalues($questions )
{
 foreach($questions as $x=>$x_value)
        {
            $questionID = $x;
            $question_answer = $x_value;

           print  $questionID;
           print $question_answer;
        }it print some thing like this 0(1,hi)1(3,123)2(37,ss)3(58,connect)4(59,no)5(47,s)6(48,f)7(49,u)8(50,p) How can I access(values of 58)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here.